# SQL Delete duplicate rows in the table without primary key on SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

[image: This is the table I want to delete duplicate]

So I want to DELETE the duplicate rows not just FIND IT
My current code can only let me know which ROWS have to be deleted.
But I am confusing how to "DELETE" them from my target table.
Any suggestion?

```
WITH tmp AS
(
    SELECT
     Code
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Code) AS ROWNUMBER
    FROM CouponCode
)

SELECT *
FROM tmp
WHERE ROWNUMBER > 1
```

Comment: You could simply select into a temp table, clear out the existing table and insert into the now cleaned table all results from the temp table.

Comment: @JakoBasson yes you are correct. What I am thinking is if we have a millions of data rows in the table, it could be slow if we copy data to a new table and rebuild later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just change your `select` to a `delete`, basically:

```
WITH tmp AS (
      SELECT Code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Code) AS ROWNUMBER
      FROM CouponCode
)
DELETE tmp
    WHERE ROWNUMBER > 1;
```

Comment: Wow..I didn't know that CTE can let me modify original table directly. 
Can I say CTE is the same as VIEW in this point,
since we can also modify original table by modifying view

Comment: @Aiden . . . Yes.  Both CTEs and Views have the same rules for being updatable (well, you can define a trigger on a view as well, but that is another matter).

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**:

Select distinct rows into temporary table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Code, ExpiredDate 
INTO temp_CouponCode
FROM CouponCode
```

**Step 2**:

Empty original table:

```
truncate table CouponCode
```

**Step 3**:

Copy data from temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO CouponCode
SELECT Code, ExpiredDate 
FROM temp_CouponCode
```

**Step 4**:

Remove temporary table:

```
DROP TABLE temp_CouponCode
```